# How do I initiate a view control from AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

*Information*

I am using Storyboard to add views. In my storyboard, I have 1 view controller and 1 Tab Bar Controller.

What I am trying to accomplish is a check to see whether or not the user is using my program for the first time, and if so, instead of showing the tab bar controller, it would show the initial view controller.

Here is my code that contains the error in AppDelegate.m at the [self presentViewController..].

The Storyboard ID for my Tab Bar Controller is 'TabBarController'.

Please note that ViewController.h & ViewController.m is UNTOUCHED.

*Code*

**GlobalHeader.h**

```
#ifndef dirt_GlobalHeader_h
#define dirt_GlobalHeader_h

BOOL RegisterCheck;

#endif
```

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GlobalHeader.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    RegisterCheck = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"RegisterCheck"];

    if (!RegisterCheck)
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"RegisterCheck"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
    else
    {
        UIStoryboard *MainStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *TabBarController = [MainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarController"];
        [self presentViewController:TabBarController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

I thank anyone for any contributions towards my question.

I would also like to say that the Visual Studio IDE is much easier to use then this XCODE (that I am unfamiliar with).

Comment: By the way, the solution to your problem is probably best handled in the `viewDidLoad` method of your default initial `viewController`, particularly if you intend to come back to this after showing the 1-time, first-time scene.

Comment: Well the initial view controller will be the registration page if the user has not used the program before so should the code not be in the AppDelegate?

Comment: You stated you want to show the tab bar controller to first time users, but your code is attempting to show it to existing users. Can you clarify which one is correct?

Comment: Oh my bad Timothy Moose, let me clarify (I did not notice my typing error). I want the tab bar controller to be shown to existing users and the view controller to be only shown to new users (hence the code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that instead of presenting the tab bar controller

```
[self presentViewController:TabBarController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

you should just be setting it as the root view controller (because you're not going to ever return to the initial view controller).

```
self.window.rootViewController = TabBarController;
```

Comment: Timothy, the presenting of the tab bar controller is where the error arises; however, by inputting your second piece of code to replace the error risen piece of code *the presenting of the tab bar controller*, it seems to work just fine on build and debug without any warnings and errors.

My only question would be is; By inputting this code into the AppDelegate, is this acceptable code in terms of correctness? Or was this thought process of putting it in the AppDelete totally incorrect and are there better ways?

Comment: I think the better approach would be to set the tab bar controller as the initial controller in your storyboard and then present the registration form modally to first time users. After registration, you'd naturally return to the tab bar controller by dismissing the registration form. The way you're doing it now, its not clear how you get back to the tab bar controller? You probably need to present the modal form in the tab bar controller's `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` (not sure which). Doing it in the app delegate is probably too early. Might be able to say more if you show the error.

Comment: The error for the piece of code [self presentViewController:TabBarController animated:YES completion:nil];

is

No visible @interface for 'AppDelegate' declares the selector 'presentViewController:animated:completion:'

HOWEVER, I fully agree with how I should set the tab bar controller as the initial controller.

Answer (score 1):

the better way is to load the tabbarcontroller in both cases, check if the user runs app for first time in the first view-controller of tabbarcontroller ,then present the viewcontroller from inside